# Event communication between IoC elements

Tags: c#, events, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle.Windsor IoC for loading plugins on runtime. These plugins provide both logic and UI implementation, such as overview and detail view panes to be inserted into my applications main window. Each provided interface implementation contains a path that distinctly references it, and the registration of the classes is in transient lifestyle mode.

Now, it seems that I am running into trouble considering communication between (UI) components: Normally I would have added delegate methods to the event queue of the UI elements inside the main windows code. But since the main window does not know anything specific about the events of the loaded controls, this would not work.

My first workaround would be to resolve the registered instance from the IoC container and attach to its event queue -- but I'm not sure if this works with transient lifestyle mode and not linking to libraries leaves me unaware of the event signatures. (What if an element from library A wants to watch another libraries event queue?)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you add some information regarding what trouble you are runnning into? Some code? Some errors?

Comment: Possibly vaguely related: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/06/dependency-injection-and-events

Comment: @samy: There are no actual errors as there's not much code until now. It's just a matter of which approach to choose.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank, I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Event Wiring Facility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Event-Wiring-Facility.ashx) could help you setup the communication between your different components. It is a facility that lets you decouple events in Windsor.

Comment: Thanks. After implementing a quick and dirty solution using reflection API I figured out that the EventWiringFacility internally works in a similar way. I'm still not quite happy with the way to use it as it is described here: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.de/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-6-event.html Plus, I'm unsure how to handle binding to components that are not available.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to deal with more complex structures (such as custom EventArgs implementations) in a good way. I have central data structures in my core application which is linked, but maybe the component framework is required to allow to define something new which then is not linked on compile-time. Or am I looking into a completely wrong direction?

Comment: Maybe you should start another question more specific to Event Wiring Facility, with code samples. This way you may be able to catch people who have used it in the same way you're trying to